# iOS8: View to Layer Animation

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, uianimation

I would like to convert this `View` based animation below into `Layer` based.

```
@IBOutlet weak var constraintTopContainerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var value:CGFloat

    switch (someTag)
    {
    case 1:
        value = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height / 3)
    case 2:
        value = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height / 2)
    case 3:
        value = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height * 0.8)
    default:
        value = 0.0
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0,
        options: nil, animations: {

        self.constraintTopContainerHeight.constant = value
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

How do I get a `Constraint` to use `Layer` based animation instead of the current `View` based animation.  Code please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should set your constraint outside of your UIView animation.

Also, you can't animate constraints with Core Animation.

The auto-layout guide from Apple explains.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html